# Bootstrap DatePicker Changing Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker with "Disabling dates in the past and dependent disabling." I'm following [the instructions](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) to the word but I am unable to change the format,Reason is this might be missing / not understanding something in the documentation. Would greatly appreciate if someone could give me a solution.

**UI Example:**

[image]

**My Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //CHANGE DATE FORMAT
      format: "dd-mm-yyyy" //results in a syntax error    

    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
      onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
      }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
      }
      checkin.hide();
      $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');
    var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
      onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
      }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
})
```

I have created a [JSFIDDLE here.](https://jsfiddle.net/leela89/6hjp780L/1/#&togetherjs=cCFVEquGJJ)

Comment: Please Check Your fiddle its not allowng to pick the date

Comment: Did you try `dd-mm-yy` instead?

Comment: @Kabali fiddle working now

Comment: @SandeepNayak please check fiddle it is returning same date format despite doing `dd-mm-yy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize your datepicker by adding an HTML attribute to the input field. See example:

```
<input type='text' name="pickupDate" id="dpd1" 
 class="form-control" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" />
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hjp780L/18/)

This fiddle renders the date in your custom format, and it's value is also accessable in the same format. ( e.g. `$('#dpd2').val()` )

Comment: I want to hug you right now, I have been stuckon this for an hour....thank you sooo much

Comment: Happy to help @Marilee, insufficient documentation can be painful. Please remember to upvote & accept. :)